# TCPDF On Next Page Header Goes Downwards

Tags: pdf, position, margin, tcpdf

i am using TCPDF to generate pdf report. But i am having a wired issue, on first page header starts from right/correct y position but from 2nd page onward it goes downwards...

here is my code i am using:

```
<?php

    require_once('./../../../Classes/tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php');
    require_once('./../../../Classes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    class MYPDF extends TCPDF
    {
    
        //Page header
        public function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            $this->Image('./../../../images/bdGovt-Logo.gif', 5, 8, 25, '', 'GIF', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
            $this->Image('./../../../images/SEQAEP-Logo.gif', 275, 8, 15, '', 'GIF', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
            // Title
            $this->ln();
            $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Government Of People\'s Republic Of Bangladesh', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
            $this->ln();
            $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Secondary Education Quality & Access Enhancement Project (SEQAEP)', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
            $this->ln();
            $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Award Confirmation Form For Stipend And Tution', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
            $this->ln();
            $this->SetFont('', 'B', 10);
            $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Semester: Jan - Jun 2015', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
            $this->ln();
        }
    
        // Page footer
        public function Footer()
        {
            // Position at 15 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-20);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
            $this->MultiCell(93, 0, str_repeat('_', 45) . "\r\n" . 'Signature of Head of the Institute' . "\r\n" . 'Include Name with Official Seal', 0, 'C', 0, 0);
            $this->MultiCell(94, 0, str_repeat('_', 45) . "\r\n" . 'Signature of Upazila Secondary Education Officer' . "\r\n" . 'Include Name with Official Seal', 0, 'C', 0, 0);
            $this->MultiCell(93, 0, str_repeat('_', 45) . "\r\n" . 'Signature of Bank Officer' . "\r\n" . 'Include Name with Official Seal', 0, 'C', 0, 0);
            $this->ln();
            // Page number
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() .' of ' . $this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        }
    }

    $pdf = new MYPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'A3', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    
    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator('Mobile: +8801717219006');
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Mohammad Kamrul Hassan');
    $pdf->SetTitle('Siam Computer');
    $pdf->SetSubject('Email: support@siamcomputer-bd.com');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('www.siamcomputer-bd.com');
    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(10, 27, 10);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
    // set cell padding
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(1.000125, 1.000125, 1.000125, 1.000125);
    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $strSInfoName = array('Location Code:', 'Bank Branch Code:', 'Bank Branch Name:', 'Division Name:', 'District Name:', 'Upazila Name:', 'Institute ID:', 'Institute Name:', 'EIIN No:');
    $strSInfoValue = array('20902', '05229', 'GUNAGARI', 'CHITTAGONG', 'CHITTAGONG', 'BANSHKHALI', '01000400', 'MONAYEM SHAH AULIA HIGH SCHOOL', '104054');
    $pdf->ln();
    //file_put_contents('./wtf.txt', $pdf->GetY());
    foreach($strSInfoName as $key => $value)
    {
        $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $strSInfoName[$key], 0,  0, 'L', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(75, 5, $strSInfoValue[$key], 0,  0, 'L', 0);
        $pdf->ln();     
    }
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 8);
    $pdf->SetY(27);
    $pdf->SetX(165);
    $pdf->Cell(125, 0, 'Institution Summary', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->ln();     
    $pdf->SetX(165);
    $pdf->Cell(15, 11, 'Class', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 11, 'Students', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(90, 0, 'Bellow Figures Showed In Taka', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->ln();     
    $pdf->SetX(165);
    $pdf->Cell(35, 0, '', 0,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, 'Stipend', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, 'Tution', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, 'SSC Exam Fees', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, 'Total', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->ln();     
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $strDummyArray = array_fill(0, 6, '00');
    $strDummyArray = array_fill(0, 6, $strDummyArray);
    $strSizeArray = array(15, 20, 20, 20, 30, 20);
    foreach($strDummyArray as $row)
    {
        $pdf->SetX(165);
        foreach($row as $key=>$col)
        {
            $pdf->Cell($strSizeArray[$key], 0, $col, 1,  0, 'C', 0);
        }
        $pdf->ln();     
    }
    $pdf->ln();
    $pdf->ln();     
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 8);
    $pdf->Cell(10, 0, 'Class:', 0,  0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $pdf->Cell(10, 0, '6', 0,  0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->ln();     

    $pdf->ln();     
    $pdf->Cell(7.5, 0, 'SL', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(60, 0, 'Student Information', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(15, 0, 'Stipened', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, 'Photo', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(37.5, 0, 'Signature', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(7.5, 0, 'SL', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(60, 0, 'Student Information', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(15, 0, 'Stipened', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 0, 'Photo', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(37.5, 0, 'Signature', 1,  0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->ln(); 

    $pdf->AddPage();

    //Close and output PDF document
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.pdf"', false);
    $pdf->Output('test-' . time() . '.pdf', 'I');   
?>
```

and this is how it looks on generated pdf (screenshots):

Page-1:
[image: Page 1 Screenshot]

Page-2: (first line text (header) position get changed)
[image: Page 2 Screenshot]

i want it start from same position on every page as first page

hope that makes sense? :)